# Branch then rollback parent branch in TFS

Tags: tfs, rollback, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I'm not very experienced with TFS, and I can't find a way to do what I want.

OK, so we have a main branch in TFS, and we began new development on this branch. We totally forgot to create a new one before beginning the modifications.

What I would like to have at the end is my main branch in the state before the modifications (I have the exact Changeset number), and a Development branch with the work in progress...

Here's what I did:

- Branched the main branch in its current state to a Development branch
- Rolled back the main branch to the latest Changeset before we began the modifications

At this point, I think I was OK, but when I tried to merge the Development branch to the main one, VS stated, correctly, that it couldn't find any Changesets that were checked-in to my Development branch but not to my main one, as the rollback didn't delete the Changesets but just added a new one, with a rollback operation.

I thought maybe checking-in something new in the Development branch would unblock this, but unfortunately, only the latest (post-branching) check-ins seem to be eligible for merging.

I surely did something wrong, or not the right way.

Anybody has an explanation and an idea of how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3):

Because your situation happens quite often (working on a main branch, only later to realize you should have branched), this is use case is supported by TFS (both command line and within Visual Studio).

Instead of specifying `By Latest` (default) or, `By: Latest Version`, you want to specify `By: Changeset` and select the last check-in that should be included in the branch. All check-ins after that are excluded from the branch, but can be merged afterwards (cherry-picking changesets if necessary).

Alternatively, you can get a specific version in your workspace (Get Specific Version) and specify `By: Workspace` when creating the branch. By date or label are also valid choices but I don't use them that often.

Comment: This is the much better solution! Branch by Changeset version allows you to create a branch from any point in the past. Don't mess with Rollback unless you absolutely have to. And never mess with Rollback to fix merge issues ;).

Answer (score 0):

A rollback is not how you would traditionally think of a rollback. It reverts the code back to the state you want, but you need to check-in the rollback as a new change. This preserves the full history of the code, including the rollback.

I would suggest you:

1. Delete your child branch
2. Put your parent branch in the state you want it, even if you have a few additional check-ins and rollbacks.
3. Once everything is fully checked-in, then branch to your child branch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I do what you suggest, my child branch won't include the latest modifications, it'll just be a copy of my parent branch, which will be in the state it was before we began the modifications. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: OK, Here's what I ended up doing: I kept a local copy of the source with the modifications, deleted my Development branch, then created a new Development branch from the Main one (still in the state before the modifications). Then checked-out the whole Development branch and pasted the local copy of the source with the modifications. Still had to manually delete/add items in TFS as the copy/paste operation doesn't trigger these actions. In the end it's manual, very error-prone, but I got it working. Still interested in another solution if you have one. Thanks :-)

Comment: That path is probably what I would have done as well. The only additional step I would have done would have been to run a code compare over the two solutions before I checked it in to make sure my true changes are there.

Answer (score 0):

A rollback being a normal changeset, you can rollback it like any other changeset. Here's what you could have done:

1. Create a development branch from your main branch.
2. Rollback unwanted changes in the main branch.
3. Check in the rollback in the main branch. This creates changeset #XYZ.

At this point, continue your developements in the development branch. You can also check in changes in the main branch. When done with development:

4. Rollback the rollback (the changeset #XYZ) in the main branch.
5. Merge changes from the development branch to the main branch.

The last action should merge only the changes done in the development branch after the branching.

Depending on the complexity of your changes and branch configuration, this could be the easiest way to go.